# iis rewrite keep path (keep everything but the file name)

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

attempting to re route

> https://xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/FOB_Main.aspx?FOB=O to
>   https://xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/FOB_Main_Rewrite.aspx?FOB=O
>
> and
>
> https://xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/testdev/FOB_Main.aspx?FOB=O to
>   https://xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/testdev/FOB_Main_Rewrite.aspx?FOB=O
>
> and
>
> https://xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/net/prodmirror/FOB_Main.aspx?FOB=O to
>   https://xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/net/prodmirror/FOB_Main_Rewrite.aspx?FOB=O

so retain everything before an aspx page and the query string. and replace it with a new aspx page.   (replace only the filename and keep everything else)

here is my attempt.

```
  <rule name="Fob_Main_decommisioned" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^fob_main.aspx" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/FOB_Main_Rewrite.aspx" redirectType="Temporary" />
  </rule>
```

this is working fine for

> https://xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/FOB_Main.aspx?FOB=O to
>   https://xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/FOB_Main_Rewrite.aspx?FOB=O

but it is changing.

> https://xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/testdev/FOB_Main.aspx?FOB=O to
>   https://xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/FOB_Main_Rewrite.aspx?FOB=O

I also attempted

```
<rule name="Fob_Main_decommisioned" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^fob_main.aspx" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{HTTP_HOST}/FOB_Main_Rewrite.aspx" redirectType="Temporary" />
      </rule>
```

but now I am getting

> https://xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/testdev/xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/FOB_Main_Rewrite.aspx?FOB=O

I also attempted

```
<rule name="Fob_Main_decommisioned" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(^.*)fob_main.aspx" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}FOB_Main_Rewrite.aspx" redirectType="Temporary" />
  </rule>
```

but I am back to

> https://xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/FOB_Main_Rewrite.aspx?FOB=O

(it is removing the testdev again)

interestingly using this rule

```
 <rule name="Fob_Main_decommisioned" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="(^.*)fob_main.aspx" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}FOB_Main_Rewrite.aspx" redirectType="Temporary" />
```

and directly typing into the browser

> https://xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/testdev/testdev/FOB_Main.aspx?FOB=O

re routes me to the page I would like to go to.

> https://xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/testdev/FOB_Main_Rewrite.aspx?FOB=O

Comment: `testdev` is your sub application or virtual directory in IIS?

Comment: it is a sub application

Comment: And did you add this rule inside `testdev` application or in `root`?

Comment: it is in the web.config file in the testdev application (and all other sub applications for that matter so in all the web config files for all of our apps development, production mirror, Unit test etc.))

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: Actually, my last web rule will for for root application as well

Answer (score 0):

This rule looks correct (if you placed this rule in root application):

```
<rule name="Fob_Main_decommisioned" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(^.*)fob_main.aspx" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}FOB_Main_Rewrite.aspx" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

This rule will work, if you placed it in sub application:

```
<rule name="Fob_Main_decommisioned" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^fob_main.aspx" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="FOB_Main_Rewrite.aspx" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

Most probably you back to `https://xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/FOB_Main_Rewrite.aspx?FOB=O`, because browser cached your wrong redirect before. Can you please do this steps:

1. Apply this rule
2. Clear cache in your browser
3. Try to open https://xxxxx.aaa.bb.cc.dd/testdev/FOB_Main.aspx?FOB=O

Comment: tried that. still same result. even tried a different browser just to make sure

Comment: May be other rule is processing this request before. Try to put this rule as first rule in web.config

Comment: updated my question to show what happens if I put in /testdev/testdev (it went to testdev) I tried /testdev/testdev/testdev and it went to testdev/testdev